# Set css style on first row of the table on case first row has rowspan

Tags: css, html-table

I have many table, want to set css style on first row of the table on case first row has rowspan.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="2" width="110">Name</td>
<td width="110">Size</td>
<td width="110">Status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter</td>
<td>true/false</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Code A</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>false</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

With this style I tried to change first row:

```
thead tr:first-child,
tbody tr:first-child {
  background-color: #1DA6C0;color: #fff;
}
```

So I looking for a css style to change table just like Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it in Javascript background using:

**nth-child(-n+${rowspan})**

Eg.

```
let tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
let td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
let rowspan = td.rowSpan? td.rowSpan:1; 
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`tbody tr:nth-child(-n+${rowspan})`);
for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].style.background = '#1DA6C0';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xugL8s9b/10/

Comment: Could you please check this https://jsfiddle.net/sarzin/mrda7s6x/1/ please, because your code doesn't work well on this sample. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because it's for a single table, you will have to loop through the tables in your case eg.https://glitch.com/edit/#!/fortunate-habitual-moth
Make modifications as per your use case :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with CSS.
You have to dynamically add the styles to the cells depending on the row-span.
Here I am assuming that you can have row-span only on the 1st cell of tbody.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
   $("#mytable tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
    let rowspan = this.getAttribute("rowspan")
    var css = `tbody tr:nth-child(-n+${rowspan}) {background-color: #1DA6C0;color: #fff;}`,
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
    head.appendChild(style);
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) {
     style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } 
    else {
     style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
  });
 });
</script>
```