# Set css style on first row of the table on case first row has rowspan - multi table

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are many tables, I want to set css style on first row of the table on case where first row has `rowspan`.
According this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783573/set-css-style-on-first-row-of-the-table-on-case-first-row-has-rowspan/61784225), I find a way to set style. but there is a bug on case multi table.

Need to set style on first row and rowspan of it, just like this image:
[image]

Here is the script code:

```
document.querySelectorAll("table").forEach(table => {
  let tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  let td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
  let rowspan = td.rowSpan ? td.rowSpan : 1;
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(`tbody tr:nth-child(-n+${rowspan})`);
  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.background = "#1DA6C0";
  }
});
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/sarzin/mrda7s6x/5/

Comment: as shown in the screenshot, first is a normal table and you want to style the first row assume a bgColor: red, now in the second screenshot, which one should be red the heading part or the value part

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Except to have background on first row(row and rowspan) of each table. So first table shouldn't have background on second row of it.

Comment: can you add the expected result as a screenshot, sorry i didn't completely understood

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS question updated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Detect the needed rowspan for particular table. Extend the selector string for querySelectorAll function as needed.
2. Run querySelectorAll function on that particular table, not for whole document

Applying above two points, your js code should be something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("table").forEach(table => {
    let tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  let tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
  let selectorStr ="tbody tr:nth-child(1)"

  let maxRowspan = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if(maxRowspan < tds[i].rowSpan)
    {
        maxRowspan = tds[i].rowSpan
      selectorStr += " , tbody tr:nth-child(" + maxRowspan + ")"
    }
  }

  var nodes = table.querySelectorAll(selectorStr)

  for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i].style.background = "#1DA600";
  }
});
```

[Here is my edit](https://jsfiddle.net/v8jnx2o3/6/) on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I actually would use `th` instead of `td` for the first row. First, if it's a header `th` is a better choice anyway and second you don't need any js for solving this.

```css
th {
  background-color: #1DA6C0;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="64">8"</th>
      <th width="64">6"</th>
      <th width="64">5"</th>
      <th width="64">4"</th>
      <th width="64">3"</th>
      <th width="74">2"</th>
      <th width="100">inch</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">76</td>
      <td rowspan="2">69</td>
      <td rowspan="2">48</td>
      <td rowspan="2">27</td>
      <td rowspan="2">20</td>
      <td rowspan="2">11</td>
      <td rowspan="2" width="100">A</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" width="110">Status</th>
      <th width="110">time</th>
      <th width="110">power</th>
      <th rowspan="2" width="110">second status</th>
      <th width="110">D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>( bar )</th>
      <th>D1 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>(B)</td>
      <td>25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Honestly, this answer is better performance-wise and using <th> is a good practice. My answer was about how you can modify js code for desired effect. I'll upvote this.